# Do notebook drives also work in desktops?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, ssd

So, I've been thinking of getting a Solid State Drive to install on my Desktop PC. However, most of the ssd's avaliable at my location are notebook drives (2.5"). In general, will these work on a desktop PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the main difference between desktop and laptop hard drives is the size, but the connectors might be different too. Double check what you've got in your desktop. Converters are available.

[This page](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000649.htm) has some more information.

> A user will need to purchase a laptop conversion kit or adapter that will include a small PCB that connects to the laptop hard drive and has a standard 40 pin IDE connector and power connector on it.
>
> Because this will also be a non standard upgrade for a desktop computer if you plan on keeping this hard drive in the desktop computer and are not just using it to backup or transfer information you will also need a mounting bracket to put the 2.5" drive in a 3.5" bay or a 5.25" (5 1/4") bay.

Comment: IDE laptop drives used a smaller connector, which would work with a desktop IDE interface with the appropriate adapter. SATA connectors should be the same on both desktop & laptop drives.  tho if actually installed in a laptop they may get some kind of wonky-looking header connector. that would just pop off to reveal the actual SATA data/power connectors underneath.

Comment: Great, so if my motherboard already carries SATA connectors, I shouldn't even need the converter right?

Comment: I guess quack already answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as know a SATA connector, which (most?) SSD drives comes with, for 2.5" and 3.5" are the same, so it should not be a problem to use a 2.5" drive in a PC.

Comment: The beauty so far is the location and distance of power and data connectors seems standardized with sata, so all sata drives regardless of size fits into the same backbone headers as well - that's just so sweet, advancements in pc technology bringing server-class solutions to your home at no extra cost ;)